# How was Anakin able to cut Master Windu's hand?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Master Windu was a very powerful Jedi who was comparable to Yoda. Why couldn't Windu's reflexes block Anakin's attack?

Comment: @Richard No. He cut hand of Windu, too. Hey, there are lots of hand cut in Star Wars similar to Pit. Luke and Anakin were also the victim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The novelisation makes it pretty clear that Windu was too focused on killing Palpatine to worry about what Anakin was up to. He never suspected him of siding with the Emperor in any serious way and he certainly wouldn't have expected Anakin to actually injure him.

> “I need him alive!” Skywalker shouted. “I need him to save Padme!”
>
> Mace thought blankly, Why? And moved his lightsaber toward the fallen
>   Chancellor.
>
> Before he could follow through on his stroke, a sudden arc of blue
>   plasma sheared through his wrist and his hand tumbled away with his
>   lightsaber still in it and Palpatine roared back to his feet and
>   lightning speared from the Sith Lord’s hands and without his blade to
>   catch it, the power of Palpatine’s hate struck him full-on.
>
> **He had been so intent on Palpatine’s shatterpoint that he’d never
>   thought to look for Anakin’s.**
>
> Dark lightning blasted away his universe. He fell forever.

Comment: Wow, that sentence has a lot of *and*s...

Comment: Windu didn't have 'is 'and by the end of it.

Comment: The fact that the novelisation also says that Windy "fell forever" doesn't draw _absolutely anything else it says_ into question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I've seen more than a few people argue that the lack of a canonical death for Windu means that he could be alive (* sheesh *)

Comment: Heck, Darth Maul being *cut in half* doesn't make him dead.