# How fast did Anakin have to swing his lightsaber to cut off Mace Windu's hand?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, revenge-of-the-sith

If a Jedi can move their lightsaber so quickly that they can block consecutive shots from a blaster rifle, how fast did Anakin have to swing his lightsaber so that Mace was not able to block it?

Mace was a pretty tough Jedi right? So of all the Jedi, he should have some pretty fast reflexes.

I know Anakin had the element of surprise, **BUT**, his attack came in the middle of a pretty hefty fight, so Mace would have been very alert and ready for anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's two questions here;

- **How fast did Anakin swing the blade**?

The answer being about 15mph, factoring in that it took 6 film frames (at 1/24th of a second) for the blade to travel along its (approximately) two 2 metre swing. Note that Windu is swinging downwards at roughly half the speed that Anakin's blade is travelling upwards. That means that the **the combined speed was around 25mph.**

[image]

- **How fast did the lightsaber need to be traveling to overcome Windu's reflexes?**

The answer is that Windu [wasn't concentrating on Anakin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/74197/20774).
**He would have missed him at *any* speed.**

Answer (score -1):

I think the quickness isn't the issue since the Jedi can technically sense the future. I think that since Mace Windu was intent on killing Sidious, which is against the Jedi code, he wasn't as intune with the Force as he should have been at that exact time. That's why he didn't see Anakin's swing coming. The speed didn't matter.

Comment: Sidious is a Sith. I think killing a Sith is the most Jedi thing anyone can do.

Answer (score -2):

Lightsabers are blades of pure energy (heat, laser, ect...) They cut through anything that hasn't had its density enhanced like butter. A human body isn't extraordinary therefore it wouldn't have mattered how fast Anakin would have swung his lightsaber, the hand would have come off even if he had just rested it on Windu's wrist.
As for why Mace Windu didn't block the attack...
Mace Windu saw Anakin as a fellow jedi regardless of his mistrust of him. Damn near every jedi of that time were so prejudice against the sith that he had assumed that Anakin would have stood by him and had no intention or reason to fight Anakin. 
Nor can I fault him. A powerful Sith Lord requires all of your focus to defeat.
And if I may be so bold as to go one step further... Mace Windu uses Vaapad as his lightsaber style of choice, this style requires him to place his foot into the dark side of the force. Metaphorically speaking. Again, jedi of that time were so prejudice against the dark side of the force that Windu was also trying to stay in control of himself as well as using the vaapad style. Mix that with expecting an attack at any moment from Darth Sidious and my original point is not even needed.